# DisplayFor and DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I fetch data dependent on survey_id from database as IEnumerable. I show data on DropDownList with the code below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.question_id, new SelectList(Model.Question, "Id", "question"), "--- Choose Question ---", new { @class="anketDropDown" })
```

But, I want to do this with DisplayFor. How can I do this if it's possible?

Comment: It's possible, but you'll need to build a custom display template.

Comment: How do you want it to be shown?

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud  Can you show me an example or share website link about this build thing.

Comment: @Jonesy I want to display the questions one by one and there will be the answer part under of the questions like the survey application.

Comment: Why not just create a partial view accepting a model of `Question`

Comment: You need to create an `EditorFor` not a a `DisplayFor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom display template:

Create a template file: `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/YourTemplate.cshtml`:

In that file:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourModelType>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Property 1</th>
        <th>Property 2</th>
    </tr>
    // e.g. print data rows in a loop 
</table>
```

But bear in mind you may need editor template (`Html.EditorFor`), since your model is survey containing questions. You probably want answers from users retrieved with their responses, aren't you? They would deliver data within the form and submit to the server, you likely have to bind the post model to one of your action parameters. Just for sake.

Comment: Using a `DisplayTemplate` for rendering a `DropDownList` does not make much sense. An `EditorTemplate` should be created, since `DropDownList` as an input field used to edit data, not to display data.

Comment: Agree 100%. That's why I edited my answer, but you were just few second faster :)